# Is there integer quadratic programming or constraint programming solver supporting integer values about 10^54?

Tags: constraint-programming, clpfd

I already have tried IBM constraint programming optimizer, but there are only 64-bit integers.

Comment: There is a Prolog based [tag:clpfd] system with arbitrary integers. So you can say `abs(X) #< 7^7^7`. See the tag.

Comment: The currently most performant version is called [clpz](https://github.com/triska/clpz/) and requires SICStus Prolog.